# Why does bootstrap not show some of my elements?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a custom theme I have found on the Internet for bootstrap. when I add a new "Row" for my grid system things get a bit messed up,
I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I do belive is styling problem, since it does not appear to show me what I want it do show so when I load the page i see the following

if you need further information to be able to help me I be glad to give it 
[image: Pic example 1]

and a scroll bar on the browser (allowing you to scroll down)

by doing so for a second you can see what else should have been there  like so

[image: pic example 2]

but the it disspears , I will share my code if anyone can help me, I not an exprienced prgoramer but I am trying to get there. 
here is the code for  viewHero.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
//error_reporting(0);
//ini_set('display_errors', 0);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"  >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">     



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

    <title>Overblog</title>
</head>
<body >
    <header class="cd-main-header">
        <a href="#0" class="cd-logo"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a>

        <div class="cd-search is-hidden">
            <form action="#0">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div> <!-- cd-search -->

        <a href="#0" class="cd-nav-trigger">Menu<span></span></a>

        <nav class="cd-nav">
            <ul class="cd-top-nav">

                <li class="has-children account">

                    <ul>


                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> <!-- .cd-main-header -->

    <main class="cd-main-content">
        <nav class="cd-side-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="cd-label">Main</li>
                <li class="has-children overview">
                    <a href="#0">Blog</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#0">Latest news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Public Test Region</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">RedPost (Redit)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children notifications active">


                <li class="has-children comments">
                    <a href="#0">Guides</a>

                </li>

                <li class="has-children users">
                    <a href="#0">Hereos</a>

                </li>

            </ul>

        </nav>

    <style>

body
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.fb-profile img.fb-image-lg{
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;  
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fb-image-profile
{
    margin: -90px 10px 0px 50px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 20%; 
}

@media (max-width:768px)
{

.fb-profile-text>h1{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:16px;
}

.fb-image-profile
{
    margin: -45px 10px 0px 25px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 20%; 
}
}
 h2{font-size:40px;
        }
        </style>     
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">                  
    <?php 
//show users code.
           define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
echo "<br/>";
                require SITE_ROOT . '\includes\loadHeroProfile.php';
    ?>
    </div>
 <div class="row"> 
      <div class='col-lg-4'>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
     </div>

    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->  

        </div>

    </main> <!-- .cd-main-content -->
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the loadHeroProfile.php

```
<?php 
//show users code.


require SITE_ROOT . '\includes\db_connect.php';
//create connection and check it
 global $connect;
$ids = intval($_GET['ids']);

$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,nickname,avatar,name,age,occupation,operations,affiliation,difficulty,ability,tips,story FROM heroes WHERE id=$ids");
$result->execute(); 
 while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $nickname = $row["nickname"];
    $avatar = $row["avatar"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $age = $row["age"];
    $occ = $row["occupation"];
    $opp = $row["operations"];
    $aff = $row["affiliation"];
    $diff = $row["difficulty"];
    $ability = $row["ability"];
    $tips = $row["tips"];
    $story = $row["story"];

    $avatar =  "./img/" . $avatar;
  echo "   <div class='fb-profile'> ";
  echo "    <img align='left' class='fb-image-lg' src='./img/Untitled.png' alt='Profile image example'/>  ";
  echo "    <img align='left' class='fb-image-profile thumbnail' src=". $avatar ." alt='Profile image example' />  ";
  echo "        <div class='fb-profile-text'>  ";
  echo "            <h2>" . $nickname . "</h2><br/>  ";
  echo "            <p>" . $name . "</p>  ";
  echo "       </div>  ";
  echo "  </div>  ";

  }
?>
```

What can I do to fix this issue ? 
 EDIT THE FINAL HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"  >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">     



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

    <title>Overblog</title>
</head>
<body >
    <header class="cd-main-header">
        <a href="#0" class="cd-logo"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="Logo"></a>

        <div class="cd-search is-hidden">
            <form action="#0">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div> <!-- cd-search -->

        <a href="#0" class="cd-nav-trigger">Menu<span></span></a>

        <nav class="cd-nav">
            <ul class="cd-top-nav">

                <li class="has-children account">

                    <ul>


                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> <!-- .cd-main-header -->

    <main class="cd-main-content">
        <nav class="cd-side-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="cd-label">Main</li>
                <li class="has-children overview">
                    <a href="#0">Blog</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#0">Latest news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">Public Test Region</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#0">RedPost (Redit)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children notifications active">


                <li class="has-children comments">
                    <a href="#0">Guides</a>

                </li>

                <li class="has-children users">
                    <a href="#0">Hereos</a>

                </li>

            </ul>

        </nav>

    <style>

body
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.fb-profile img.fb-image-lg{
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;  
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fb-image-profile
{
    margin: -90px 10px 0px 50px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 20%; 
}

@media (max-width:768px)
{

.fb-profile-text>h1{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:16px;
}

.fb-image-profile
{
    margin: -45px 10px 0px 25px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 20%; 
}
}
 h2{font-size:40px;
        }
        </style>     
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">                  
    <br/>    <div class='fb-profile'>     <img align='left' class='fb-image-lg' src='./img/Untitled.png' alt='Profile image example'/>      <img align='left' class='fb-image-profile thumbnail' src=./img/bastion.png alt='Profile image example' />          <div class='fb-profile-text'>              <h2>Bastion</h2><br/>              <p>SST Laboratories Siege Automaton E54, "Bastion"</p>         </div>    </div>      </div>
 <div class="row"> 
      <div class='col-lg-4'>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
     </div>

    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->  

        </div>

    </main> <!-- .cd-main-content -->
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

edit the styling as requested :
note that I did not made or touch this, is a free tempalte over the internet 
reset.css

```
    /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Style.css   Find it [here](http://pastebin.com/40RYz9PU)

I can't post this because it will pass the 3k mark for posting.

Comment: It would be easier to troubleshoot if we could see the final HTML, as opposed to the PHP files.

Comment: Hey I have edited the Original post. at the bottom of it there is the final output of my html filke

Comment: Is it possible to see the active source at all?  Your code above references custom styles (reset.css, style.css) without showing how they affect the overall code.  It would also help to illustrate clearly what your DESIRED result is, versus the screenshots you've displayed.

Comment: I have added what is requested, My AIM is to get the results on the second screenshot. but when ever I laod the page I see what you can see on the 1st screenshot, when I scrol down I see the second part, but it automatically scrolls up again.  *I dont want it to have scrolling there I have no idea why is there"  Also the CSS is not mine is a FREE tamplate I have found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML that you have provided is riddled with errors and inconsistencies; I strongly recommend you review the code that your Template provided in order to ensure that these errors are not causing unexpected rendering issues.

That being said, I have created a JSFiddle showcasing corrected HTML here:

https://jsfiddle.net/embed/1pfz7yg2/show/

You can see the HTML / CSS here: https://jsfiddle.net/embed/1pfz7yg2/

From what I understand of your desired output, you want the left-hand navigation to remain static.  That being the case, the most relevant bit of CSS is:

`.cd-side-nav { position: fixed; }`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, appreciated a lot , i will get directly to work then and check the other HTML files for the same errors.

Thanks for your time